# How to calculate a division/quotient in octal numeric system?

Tags: number-systems

Im trying to make a division in octal system
$$\frac{165_{8}}{24_{8}}$$
So I have done like this using a table
$$24\times 0=0_{8}$$
$$24\times 1=30_{8}$$
$$24\times 2=50_{8}$$
$$24\times 3=74_{8}$$
$$24\times 4=120_{8}$$
$$24\times 5=144_{8}$$
$$24\times 6=170_{8}$$
$$24\times 6=214_{8}$$

Next
$$\frac{165_{8}}{24_{8}}=5.5_{8}$$
but this has a remainder of $0_{8}$

How must be done the fractional part, since when doing this in a calculator it solve the operation as $5.66_{8}$? How it was calculate the .66 fraction?

**UPDATE**
I was using the wrong values on the table, it was updated. So indeed

$$\frac{165_{8}}{24_{8}}=5.66_{8}$$

Comment: $90_8$ doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $24_8$ in the denominator is $20_{10}$.  In your table you are multiplying by $24_{10}$ and then converting to base $8$.  We have $5_8 \cdot 24_8=144_8$, so the remainder is $21_8$.  Then $\frac {21_8}{24_8}\approx 0.663_8$